# CSS Not Working if at Bottom

Tags: html, css

I have some simple CSS within html style brackets, however the only one that actually affects the page is the one on top.

```
.hot {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: black;
{

.large {
    margin-top: 1cm;
    margin-bottom: 1cm;
}
```

When hot is on top it works but large does not, and vice versa.

Comment: You have a typo... your closing bracket for the first declaration.. `{` should be `}`...

Comment: Can you reproduce in a http://jsfiddle.net and share the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, instead of using the closing bracket (`}`) you used the opening bracket (`{`). Change your code to this :-

```
.hot {
 background-color: #F7F7F7;
 border: 1px;
 border-color: black;
}                               //Typo was at this line

.large {
 margin-top: 1cm;
 margin-bottom: 1cm;
}
```